# how to display data on 2 different date ranges

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following `date` data, which is used to display MySQL data parameters

```
$tgaw=date("Y-m-10");
$tgak=date("Y-m-09", strtotime("+1 months"));
```

and I have the following query:

```
$querylembur = "SELECT SUM(total) as subtotal FROM lembur WHERE tgl between ".$tgaw." 
AND ".$tgak." AND staff =".$row['nama'];
$rslembur=mysqli_query($con,$querylembur);
$rowlembur=mysqli_fetch_array($rslembur);
```

The result I want is that the program will display data from date `:$tgaw` to date: `$tgak`

Comment: You need to enclose your literals in the query in quotes i.e. `$querylembur = "SELECT SUM(total) as subtotal FROM lembur WHERE tgl between '$tgaw' AND '$tgak' AND staff = '{$row['nama']}';` but better yet you should use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using prepared statements here, and also use the MySQL functions to add one month to the upper date in the range.

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(total) AS subtotal FROM lembur WHERE tgl BETWEEN ? AND DATE_ADD(?, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND staff = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $tgaw, $tgaw, $row['nama']);
$stmt->execute();
// fetch here
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: I presume you re-opened this, but why doesn't that show up in the edit history?

Comment: @Nick Very strange, and you might just have discovered a bug :-)

Comment: So my presumption was correct? I guess it must have all happened in the first 5 minutes but it seems closing and re-opening should always be logged.

Comment: BTW I far prefer `? + INTERVAL 1 MONTH` :)